# Edit multiple objects with Get() function Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to edit two forms in Django. A form for 'Motel' and its 'Images'. In my app, users can upload multiple images to the 'Motel' model. And now, editing the images with 'get()' function is giving me,

```
MultipleObjectsReturned get() returned more than one MotelImages -- it returned 4!
```

Models

```
class Motel(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=120)
    body= models.TextField()
    #other fields

class MotelImages(models.Model):
    motel= models.ForeignKey(Motel, default=None, related_name='images')
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to='company', verbose_name= 'Image')

class MotelImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image= forms.ImageField(label='Image',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MotelImagesForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].widget= forms.FileInput(attrs={'name':'image',
                                                         'multiple':'multiple'})
```

Views for saving the form

```
def create_motel(request):
    if request.method=="POST":

        motelForm= MotelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset=MotelImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if motelForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():

           human= True

           motel_form= motelForm.save(commit=False)
           motel_form.user= request.user
           motel_form.pub_date= datetime.datetime.now()
           motel_form.save()

           for image in request.FILES.getlist('image',[]):
                photo= MotelImages(motel=motel_form, image=image)
                photo.save()

            messages.success(request,
                         "Welldone Boy")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/view_all/')
        else:
            print motelForm.errors, formset.errors

    else:
        motelForm=MotelForm()
        formset= MotelImagesForm()
        return render(request, 'motels/add_motel.html',{'motelForm': motelForm, 'formset':formset})
```

Views for editing the form

```
@login_required
def  edit_motel(request,motel_id=None,slug=None,template_name='motel_edit.html'):
    if id:
         post=get_object_or_404(Motel,id=motel_id,slug=slug)
         images=MotelImages.objects.get(motel=motel_id)
    else:
        post=Motel(user=request.user)
        images=MotelImages(user=request.user)
    if request.POST:
        motelform=MotelForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=post)
        formset=MotelImagesForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=images)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            formset.save()
            redirect_url=reverse('moteldetail',kwargs={'motel_id':motel_id,'slug':slug})
            return render(request, 'motels/updatenotice.html')

    else:
        form=MotelForm(instance=post)
        formset= MotelImagesForm(instance=images)
    return render(request, template_name,{'formset':formset,'motelform':motelform})
```

Template for editing the form

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action=""
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in motelform.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in motelform %}
       {{ field.name }}
       {{ field }} <br />
    {% endfor %}

     {{ formset.management_form }}
          {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `if id:` or do you want `if motel_id:`?

Answer (score 0):

`images = MotelImages.objects.get(motel=motel_id)`

Since `get` can return only one object, you want to use `filter`:

`images = MotelImages.objects.filter(motel__pk=motel_id)`

`images` will be a list of the relevant images.

Comment: the filter() is giving me 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Sorry, missed out it was a foreign key. Try again with my updated answer.

Comment: still getting the same error. 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Post your full stacktrace.

Comment: filter doesn't give you just one object, it gives you a bunch of them, hence why it has no attribute _meta. Loop over what it gives you back.

Comment: I did this images=MotelImages.objects.filter(motel=motel_id) for image in images:  myimages=image and added 'myimages' as instance formset=MotelImagesForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=myimages) but I'm still getting the same queryset object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: The answer @deepspace has given you answers your original question and you should accept it. The filter giving you another error is a different business all together. You should post that as a new question wtih the full stacktrace. though you claim to have added it here, it's not.